# Proof or find counterexample to inequality (in three vars)

Tags: equation-solving

I'm trying to show 
\begin{eqnarray*}
\left(\frac{1-q^r}{1-q^n}\right)^{\frac{1}{n-r}} \left(\frac{q^n \log (q)}{\left(1-q^n\right) (n-r)}-\frac{\log \left(\frac{1-q^r}{1-q^n}\right)}{(n-r)^2}\right)>0,
\end{eqnarray*}or alternatively find a counterexample. I know $q \in (0,1)$, $n>r$ and $n, r \in \mathbb{N}$. I tried the following code:

```
derivative[q_, r_, n_] = ((1 - q^r)/(1 - q^n))^(1/(n - r)) ((q^n Log[q])/
    ((1 - q^n) (n - r)) - Log[(1 - q^r)/(1 - q^n)]/(n - r)^2)
Reduce[derivative[q, r, n] > 0 && 0 < q < 1 && n > r && r>0 && n ∈ Integers && r ∈ Integers]
FindInstance[derivative[q, r, n] <= 0 && n > r && r>0 && 0 < q && q < 1 && 
    n ∈ Integers && r ∈ Integers, {q, n, r}]
```

But each evaluation simply returns the given command (after running for multiple minutes on a brand new laptop). Is this just too complicated for Mathematica? There are only three variables, so it should be doable?

EDIT: Actually, Mathematica seems unable to do the FindInstance as soon as I add the $0<q<1$ constraint, even if I let it search for instances where the inequality holds -- but I can plot this as a function and all the values I can see are such that the inequality holds...

EDIT 2: I ended up solving this analytically; if you are interested you can see my answer at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1602299/sign-the-derivative-of-frac1-qr1-qn1-n-r-wrt-n-where-q-in/1603248#1603248

Comment: I presume that you mean `n` and `r` to be `Integers` greater than `0`.  But, your code simply says `Integers`.

Comment: Excellent catch! I reran it with r > 0 as additional restriction (see edit; n>0 follows from n>r) but still the same result :(

Comment: The first factor, `((1 - q^r)/(1 - q^n))^(n - r)^(-1)`, can be discarded, because it always is positive.  Also, the second factor can be simplified by clearing its denominator.

Comment: consider the factors seperately. Try without the integer restriction

Comment: @bbgodfrey Yes, I noticed that - but it changes nothing to do so (in terms of what Mathematica returned)..

Comment: @george2079: Just tried, no change in results

Comment: `{q -> .005, r -> 9, n -> 10}` seems to be a counterexample.

Comment: Yes, correct - awesome, thanks! How did you find it if I may ask, i.e. was there a Mathematica command I am missing or was this just by hand?

Comment: My answer turned out to be bogus, due to lack of precision in the computations.  (Thanks to @Kuba for identifying this error.).  Because `n` and `r` are discrete, you can plot your function vs `q` for lots of them. (Be sure to have a large `WorkingPrecision`.)  This is no proof but does lend credibility to your proposition.

Comment: Wow, I hadn't even thought of working precision being an issue here. Thanks again for your help!

Comment: with any specific `n,r`,  you can use `Limit[ q-> 0 or 1 ]` to show the second factor is analytically zero.  That along with the numerical plots is a "practical" proof.  Of course a mathematician would want more..

Comment: That does work, but I'd still require an argument that the inequality never drops below its left and right limits -- I just had a look at its derivative and I don't think arguing that there is only one stationary point will be an easier problem (though it seems correct from my plots)...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Beginning with the expression

```
((1 - q^r)/(1 - q^n))^(1/(n - r)) 
    ((q^n Log[q])/((1 - q^n) (n - r)) - Log[(1 - q^r)/(1 - q^n)]/(n - r)^2)
```

multiply by the positive quantity

```
(n - r)^2 (1 - q^n) ((1 - q^r)/(1 - q^n))^(-1/(n - r))
```

and `Simplify` to obtain

```
q^n (n - r) Log[q] + (-1 + q^n) Log[(-1 + q^r)/(-1 + q^n)]
```

The transformation `q^n -> x` and `r/n -> t` then reduces the number of variables from three to two.

```
x (1 - t) Log[x] + (x - 1) Log[(1 - x^t)/(1 - x)]
```

Unfortunately, `Reduce` and `FindInstance` still cannot determine whether this expression is positive.  The function can, however, be plotted (with large `WorkingPrecision` to take account of substantial precision loss in evaluating the function).

```
ContourPlot[x (1 - t) Log[x] + (x - 1) Log[(1 - x^t)/(1 - x)], {x, 0, 1}, {t, 0, 1}, 
    PlotPoints -> 100, PlotRange -> {0, 1}, FrameLabel -> {x, t}, 
    ContourLabels -> All, WorkingPrecision -> 30]
```

[image]

which appears to be positive throughout.  Also, the limiting values of the function at `x = 0`, `x = 1`, and `t=1` all are zero, while the limiting value at `x = 0` is infinite.  This does not prove the validity of the proposition in the question but does add credence to it.